# Polynomial such that in $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ $E^{k}F^{k}w=P_k(H)w$ for $Ew=0$?

Tags: representation-theory

$\newcommand{\Lie}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}$
I am trying to solve problem 2.15.1 b) from "Introduction to representation theory" by Etingof et al. The problem is stated as follows:

> Let $W$ be arbitrary representation of $\Lie{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, and $w$ be a non-zero vector of $W$ such that $Ew=0$. Find a sequence of polynomials $P_k(x)$ of degree $k > 0$ such that $E^{k}F^{k}w=P_k(H)w$.

Here $H, E, F$ are representations of generators of $\Lie{sl}_{2}$, $[H, E]=2E$, $[H, F]=-2F$, $[E, F]=H$. It is recommended by the book to first find $[E, F^{k}]$, and then use induction by $k$.

---

My attempt:
$\def\shf{\sqcup\mathchoice{\mkern-7mu}{\mkern-7mu}{\mkern-3.2mu}{\mkern-3.8mu}\sqcup}$

Let us first calculate $EF^kw$.
$$EF^kw=[E,F^{k}]w+F^kEw=[E, F^k]w$$
$$EF^kw=HF^{k-1}w+FHF^{k-2}+F^2HF^{k-3}+\dots+F^{k-1}H=H\shf F^{k-1}$$

where $\shf$ is the shuffle product. Now,
$$[E^{m+1},F^k]w=E[E^m, F^k]w+[E,F^{k}]E^{m}w=E[E^m,F^k]w=$$
$$=E^m[E,F^k]w+[E^m,F^k]Ew=E^m[E,F^k]w$$
$$=E^m(H\shf F^{k-1})w=E[E^m, F^{k}]w\implies$$
$$[E^m, F^k]w=E^{m-1}(H\shf F^{k-1})w$$.

Let us use recurrent formula:

$$[E^2, F^k]w=E[E,F^{k}]w=E(H\shf F^{k-1})w=$$
using $[E, H]=-2E$:

$$E(H\shf F^{k-1})=E\left( \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F^{j}HF^{k-1-j} \right)=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}[E, F^j]HF^{k-1-j}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F^{j}EHF^{k-1-j}=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(H\shf F^{j-1})HF^{k-1-j}-2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F^{j}EF^{k-1-j}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F^{j}HEF^{k-1-j}=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(H\shf F^{j-1})HF^{k-1-j}-2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F^{j}(H\shf F^{k-j-2})+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F^{j}H(H\shf F^{k-j-2})$$

I don't know where to go from here. I don't see a clear pattern, and the whole expression looks like a mess, and this is only the special case of $E^{2}$.

**Edit:**
I have found a proof [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2012/REUPapers/Seitz-McLeese.pdf), but it looks very non-intuitive, cumbersome, and uses the known answer to formulate the induction hypothesis. If nobody comes up with a better solution, I will try to simplify and rewrite it in a less precognitive manner.